# buffered image animation code not repainting properly

Tags: java, swing, animation, graphics, bufferedimage

Can someone please explain to me why this code is not animating the `bufferedImage` so that it travels to the new target position. note: x2 is the x-coordinate of the `bufferedImage`

```
if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("move")){
   target=x2-change;
   do{
   if (x2>target)
      x2=x2-SPEED; 
   try{Thread.sleep(10);
   }catch(Exception exc){}
   frame.repaint();
   }
   while(x2!=target);
}
```

Comment: How much research have you done into the paint process?  May be have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/). How much research have you done into "animation" or "game" engines? May be have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Answer (score 1):

> please explain to me why this code is not animating the bufferedImage

I would guess the code is executing on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. The Thread.sleep causes the `EDT` to sleep which means the GUI can't repaint itself until the animation is finished.

You were given a working example in your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34552109/131872 that uses a Swing Timer.

Why are you using Thread.sleep and not the Swing Timer???

Comment: The bufferedImage just sits there with or without the Thread.sleep and would only move to its position if i move the frame around. How would I add the Swing Timer with the Key Listener because the working example used Key Bindings which I do not know how to do :(

Comment: `the working example used Key Bindings which I do not know how to do` - its a "working example" which shows you how to do it, so I don't understand the problem. Start with the working code and modify it for your needs. Experiment and learn, don't just ignore the answer. In any case we can't tell what it wrong with your code. We have no idea how the variables are used. Again, in the "working example" you could copy/paste/compile and test the code. We can't do that with your code.